# How to apply a custom recursive function with data.table and loop over each index group-wise?

Tags: r, recursion, dplyr, data.table, dtplyr

Since I can't find an answer in below questions:

[Apply a recursive function over groups and rows without explicit for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536499/apply-a-recursive-function-over-groups-and-rows-without-explicit-for-loop)

[How do I mimic the drag functionality for new rows such as in Excel but for R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69529358/how-do-i-mimic-the-drag-functionality-for-new-rows-such-as-in-excel-but-for-r)

I'll try in asking a new question related to above. I.e, I want to apply a custom function recursively based on the output of previous values to the current row by group.

Example with a dataframe and a for loop:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df1)) df1$z[i] <- df1$z[i-1] + df1$x[i-1] - df1$y[i-1]
```

Example with a dataframe and a for loop with custom function:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df1)) df1$z[i] <- ifelse(df1$z[i-1] == df1$z[i],
                                          df1$z[i-1] + df1$x[i-1] - df1$y[i-1],
                                          df1$z[i-1] - df1$x[i-1] - df1$y[i-1])
```

However, with >1 mill rows, data.frames and for-loops are not optimal.

Is there any way to do above with `data.table` or `dtplyr` and optimized but also group-wise?

**EDIT:**
See visualization of question.

It should first initiate from 2nd row like in `for(i in 2:nrow(df)` and it should use `the custom function if and only if group[i]==group[i-1]`
[image]

Comment: `for-loops are not optimal`... based on what? Most of R uses `for` loops deep down inside, and the premise that *"`*apply` is faster than `for`"* is now a ***myth*** since it was fixed years ago. The biggest flaw I see in your loop is that you are handling groups inefficiently (and in a fragile way).

Comment: Dataframes *and* for-loops are not optimal. Based on that. Please help with the group handling then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this use of `Reduce` do the trick?

```
tmp = data.table(
  grp = c(rep(0,6), rep(1,6)),
  x=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,1,2,3,4,5,6),
  y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 10,20,30,40,50,60)
)
tmp[, z:=Reduce(f=function(z,i) z + x[i-1] - y[i-1],
                x=(1:.N)[-1],
                init=0,
                accumulate = T)
    ,by=grp
]
```

Output:

```
    grp  x  y    z
 1:   0 10  1    0
 2:   0 20  2    9
 3:   0 30  3   27
 4:   0 40  4   54
 5:   0 50  5   90
 6:   0 60  6  135
 7:   1  1 10    0
 8:   1  2 20   -9
 9:   1  3 30  -27
10:   1  4 40  -54
11:   1  5 50  -90
12:   1  6 60 -135
```

Take for example, row 4. The value in the z column is 54, which is equal to the prior row's z-value + prior row's x-value, minus prior row's y-value.

The function `f` within Reduce can take any complicated form, including `ifelse` statements. Here is an example, where I've made a function called `func`, which is a wrapper around `Reduce`. Notice that within the Reduce statement, `f` is a function taking `prev` (thanks to suggestion by @r2evans), and this function first calculates previous row's `s` value minus previous row's `t` value (this is akin to your `x[-1]-y[-1]`. Then there is an `ifelse` statement. If the difference between the prior rows `s` and `t` value (i.e. `k`) is >20, then the new value in this row will be the previous `z` value minus the product of 20-4k (i.e. `prev-(20-4k)`), otherwise it will the previous `z` value  + `k` (i.e. which is equal to your original formulation: `z[i-1]+x[i-1]-y[i-1]`)

```
func <- function(s,t) {
  Reduce(
    f=function(prev,i) {
      k=s[i-1] - t[i-1]
      ifelse(k>10, prev -(20-4*k), prev+k)
    },
    x=2:length(s),
    init=0,
    accumulate = TRUE
  )
}
```

You can then assign the value of the `func(x,y)` to z, like this:

```
tmp[, z:=func(x,y), by=.(grp)][]
```

Output:

```
    grp  x  y    z
 1:   0 10  1    0
 2:   0 20  2    9
 3:   0 30  3   61
 4:   0 40  4  149
 5:   0 50  5  273
 6:   0 60  6  433
 7:   1  1 10    0
 8:   1  2 20   -9
 9:   1  3 30  -27
10:   1  4 40  -54
11:   1  5 50  -90
12:   1  6 60 -135
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach. No, it should refer to the i-1 value of z as well.

Comment: See edited version for visualization.

Comment: Do you have some example data? If you look at my result above, you will see that the `z` value for row `i` equals `z[i-1] + x[i-1] - y[i+1]`.  For example, row 11 `z` value is -90. This is equal to `z[10] + x[10] - y[10]`, or `-54+4-40`.   My apologies if I am missing something.

Comment: @geometricfreedom, I think you're missing the elegance and correctness of langtang's code. It *does* use the previous value of `z`, though it may not be clear since the `z` in that anon-func actually refers to the `z` passed to it, not the z present in the row; the `z` passed to the anonfunc is actually the result of the previous iteration of the `Reduce` processing, which is the assignment to the previous row's `z` value ... so it *is* the previous value. Lacking a more reproducible question with sample data disproving this solution, the ball is in your court, I think langtang has it right.

Comment: If it makes it any more clear (since `Reduce` can be rather difficult to grok), I often code it using `prev` as the anonfunc first arg, which would make this `Reduce(f = function(prev, i) prev + x[i] - y[i], ...)`.

Comment: @r2evans I'll use that moving forward (i.e. naming `prev`.. ) that's very helpful reminder.

Comment: @r2evans, I'm struggling to move the function in `f` outside `Reduce`..  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do: `Reduce` is a fundamental operation here.

Comment: @r2evans, sorry, maybe I should open new question.  Here, if I define a function like this `func = function(a,b) (a*b+b/a+27-a^3)/pi`, I can then refer that `func` in Reduce like this `Reduce(func, c(1:4), accumulate = T)`, and it works, but I was unsure how do the parallel with the problem above (i.e. the usage of Reduce for the OP). Obviously, I don't need to do this, because the f is simple.  But I was curious how to define it outside  Reduce, like I did with `func`

Comment: I see ... because this function refers to data that *should* be found in the function's call tree but may not ... yeah, it's really not that simple when reducing multiple columns, unfortunately. I don't know of a generic way that would fit "well".

Comment: That is, because `Reduce` only reduces a simple list/vector and not a set of lists/vectors (i.e., multiple columns), it is not generalizable in that way. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: (I've actually pondered that very question ... the closest I came is https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945868/3358272 ...)

Comment: @r2evans helpful as always.. thanks

Comment: Thanks langtang. Probably I don't understand your code that well that is why. How do you fit in an ifelse() statement in there? Is it different from data.table::set()?

Comment: Not solved, but will mark as most helpful. It helped me discover other underlying functions.

Comment: re data.table::set(), no, you cannot use set() with by.   

re ifelse(), sure.. You can, but your example didn't require it.. , the by="grp", takes care of insuring that the formula previous z + previous x - previous y is NOT evaluate for the first row in the group.. .. Your function f can, however, be any complicated function of the values in the prior rows, including if else statements.. (see my edit)

Comment: @r2evans, I've resorted to using a wrapper around `Reduce`, which doesn't completely resolve my original query to you, but improves readability (i.e. moves the Reduce "out" of the `tmp[i,j,by]`